# How to login to redis-cli without storing password?

Tags: redis

I've configured redis-server to use password with `requirepass` option.

When running `redis-cli` I have two options to gain access to database.

1. Use `redis-cli -a mypassword` command. This stores passsword inbash history.
   Every time I run it, I need to delete history entry.
2. Use `AUTH mypassword` inside redis-cli. This option unfortunately saves your password in redis-cli, and you can look it by pressing up arrow even if you login to redis-cli without any authentication. It is literally accessible without any protection.

What is the proper way to authenticate redis-cli?

Comment: Surely your permissions must be set poorly if other folks can see your `bash` history and run `redis-cli` under your login?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Good point!

Comment: I know right. Its an oxymoron to use password for mysql, redis.. if the only way to use them is via 127.0.0.1. Still everyone is doing it, and I admit, i dont know if any security is added. If someone manages to get access of my computer, I have bigger problems anyway.

Comment: Hi, you can use FastoRedis PRO, with user authentification. All connection settings encrypted.

Answer (score 10):

You may set the password in `REDISCLI_AUTH` environment variable prior to invoking `redis-cli`. Once the variable is set, you could access `redis-cli` without specifying the password with `-a` switch. The `redis-cli` would use the password set in `REDISCLI_AUTH` while connecting to Redis server.

```
export REDISCLI_AUTH=your_secret_password
redis-cli -h hostname -p portnumber
```

Comment: Is this for default user? what about other users?

Answer (score 5):

you can type on redis-cli.

```
redis-cli -h 1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1:6379> auth mypassword
OK
```

or you can use shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n Password: 
read -s password
redis-cli -h 1.1.1.1 -a $
```

Answer (score 3):

Good question! I was confused by this problem either...

By default, the history is saved in the following file: `$HOME/.rediscli_history`. However, you can change the location of the history file by setting the history path into an environment variable: `REDISCLI_HISTFILE`. Particularly, if you set `REDISCLI_HISTFILE` as */dev/null*, `redis-cli` won't save any history.

`export REDISCLI_HISTFILE=/dev/null`

Comment: Exactly :) https://redis.io/topics/rediscli#editing-history-and-completion

Answer (score 0):

While redirecting redis history to `/dev/null` will not store the auth command, it will also lose the benefits of redis history. I don't know if there's a way to selectively ignore the redis command `AUTH mypassword`, but there is a way to make bash selectively store commands in bash history.

Authenticating with `redis-cli -a mypassword` will usually store the command in bash history, but bash history has a feature that will prevent it from storing a specific command of your choosing: if the `HISTCONTROL` environment variable has the value `ignorespace`, `ignoreboth`, or `ignorespace:ignoredups`, bash history won't store any command that begins with a space. (see https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-bash-history-more-efficiently-histcontrol)

```
$echo ${HISTCONTROL} # examine the value of HISTCONTROL
ignoreboth
```

---

With this in mind, you can conceal the password when using `redis-cli -a`:

**A)** Do a one-time authentication and don't store the call to redis-cli in bash history:

```
$ redis-cli -a mypassword #note the leading space
```

**B)** Stay authenticated for the duration of your bash session with an environment variable, but preserve the call to redis-cli in your history:

```
$ MYPASS=mypassword #note the leading space; won't be stored
$redis-cli -a ${MYPASS} #no leading space, but doesn't leak the password
```

---

You can confirm that this worked with the `history` command:

```
$history #examine bash history
$history -d 345 #delete line 345 from your history if you made a mistake and want to erase that line
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works pretty well for me on a Mac

1. Copy the password into the clipboard
2. Run the following command

```sh
# Mac only b/c of pbpaste
redis-cli -h <host> -p <port> -a $(pbpaste)
```